# Need a standard barcode reader library with dotcode support for my android app

Tags: android, barcode

I'm using Zxing library for scanning barcode in my app, but now I want to scan dotCode type of barcode through my app which is not supported in this library.

I have checked the documents of zxing and vision library, but I couldn't find dot code in the list of barcode format supported by the corresponding library.

So i need a suggsetion about which library can we use to read dotCode format.

Thanks in advance.